# Typing useState hook in react using generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-hooks

Having a custom react hook which handles input validation on text fields and check boxes.                             Working with generics since `value` can be a string or a boolean.

Trying to set `value` via `setValue` results in error `Argument of type 'Type' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Type>'.`

```
export function useInputValidation<Type>(_validationFunc = null): InputValidationState<Type> {
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Type>();

  /** handle input of control */
  const handleInput = <Type,>(_value: Type): void => {
    const result =
      _validationFunction === null
        ? { isValid: true, message: "all good" }
        : _validationFunction(_value);

    setMessage(result.message);
    setIsValid(result.isValid);
    setValue(_value);
  };

  return //...
}
```

I could bypass this problem by typing my setValue state to `any`:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<any>();
```

I tested using useState hook without generics, which is working fine:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState<string>()
setTest("someText")
console.log(test)
```

I'm assuming I need to type my useState hook in a different way, maybe with SetStateAction?
Right now I don't understand why I can type a useState hook with a explicit type, but not with a generic.

Answer (score 0):

Not passing any argument to `useState` is equivalent to passing it `undefined` so you should include `undefined` in the generic parameter:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState<Type | undefined>();
```